# Google analytics events not visible in dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to track clicks on the page. I have added GA script to my page and I can see the traffic. The next step is to track click on given button. I have added following script to my buttons:

```
onclick=gtag('event', 'Click g-store top', {
  'event_category' : 'ButtonClick',
  'event_label' : 'Click to google play'
});
```

I can see the events flowing to my dashboard under "Realtime" label as events in last 30min.
[image]

But I can't see them in more persistent way under Engagement -> Events. What am I missing ?
[image]

Comment: iIt can take up to 24h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Michele Pasani, you need to wait at least 12-24h until the events show up in the "All events" page