# Google Analytics 4 - Events are not being tracked

Tags: jquery-click-event, google-analytics-4

After switching to the new Google Analytics 4, Events are not being tracked anymore.

Here is the new snippet:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX');    
</script>
```

Right underneath I call these on click events:

```
<script>
// login
$('.btn-login').click(function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    console.log(email);
        
    gtag('event', 'login', {
        'event_category': 'Login',
        'event_label': 'Login Click',
        'value': email
    });            

    return true;
});

// menu
$('ul.nav-list > li > a').click(function () {
    var link = $(this).text();
    console.log(link);
    gtag('event', 'Menu', {
        'event_category': 'Menu',
        'event_label': 'Menu Click',
        'value': link
    });
});
   
// mailto link
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').click(function () {
    var link= $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(link);
        
    gtag('send', {
        'hitType': 'event',
        'eventCategory': 'Email Enquiry',
        'eventAction': 'Click',
        'eventLabel': link
    });
    return true;

});
```

When clicking around, I see page views but none of my clicks are showing in the Google Analytics dashboard. Can someone spot the issue?

I followed this docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Comment: I experienced similar confusion. Have you used the GA Debugger Chrome extension to validate that the event is being sent correctly? If so, try looking at the DebugView in GA or the realtime report.

As this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64577010/google-analytics-events-not-visible-in-dashboard it takes time for the events to be visible in the events report, but in my experience they do appear after 24 hours. 

The realtime / debug view helps with immediate verification that events are being recorded.

Comment: I do not see them in the DebugView (I need the extension for it?) but after looking at the link you referenced I do see it under the "Evet count by Event name" box in the the Realtime view. thanks for you help.

Comment: You’re welcome. You’ll see hits in the debug view if you send an extra ‘debug_view’ property with your hit. If you are using the google chrome extension and it is switched on, this property is set automatically. More info about it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382?hl=en I found debug view a useful tool.